# Can a Swiftui Identifiable Foreach loop select only the first 5 items

Tags: foreach, swiftui, identifiable

Howdy I have a project that only needs to display the first 5 items in the loop of over 30 items, below is my code

```
struct Introductions: Codable, Identifiable {
   let id: String
   let topIntros: String?
   let image: String
   let date: String
}

ForEach(introductions) { introduction in
   NavigationLink(destination: IntroductionDetailView(introduction: introduction)) {
      IntroductionsView(introduction: introduction)
   }
}
```

I tried using this method but xcode crashed crashed after i scrolled past the fifth item

```
ForEach(introductions, id: \.topIntros) { introduction in
   NavigationLink(destination: IntroductionDetailView(introduction: introduction)) {
      IntroductionsView(introduction: introduction)
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: That's not how we present code here.

Comment: I know i am looking for the formater, no luck yet on presenting the code the right way

Comment: got it finally Ctrl K

Comment: var body: some View {
 List {
  ForEach(introductions.startIndex..<5) { index in
   let introduction = introductions[index]
   ...
  }
 }
}

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i'ld rather prefer using a LazyVStack in this case and i didnt understand your message completely

Comment: You can add LazyVTack or whatever you want to your code for yourself, can't you?  struct ContentView: View { 
 var body: some View {
  ScrollView {
   LazyVStack {
    ForEach(introductions.startIndex..<5) { index in
     let introduction = introductions[index]
     Text(introduction.topIntros)
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

Comment: @ElTomato: Why you are insisting `introductions.startIndex`? It would be always `0` so why not just `0`? Apple: `For an instance of Array, startIndex is always zero.` Since ForEach take just Array or Range! and using Set or dic are odd!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
if (introductions.count >= 5) {
    ForEach(introductions.prefix(upTo: 5), id:\.id) { introduction in
       NavigationLink(destination: IntroductionDetailView(introduction: introduction)) {
          IntroductionsView(introduction: introduction)
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way for you:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var array: [Int] = Array(100...130)

    var body: some View {
        
        if (array.count >= 5) {
            
            ForEach(0...4, id:\.self) { index in
                
                Text(String(describing: array[index]))
      
            }
            
        }

    }
    
}
```

Here another way for you:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var array: [Int] = Array(100...130)

    var body: some View {
        
        ForEach(array.dropLast(array.count - 5), id:\.self) { item in
            
            Text(String(describing: item))

        }

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Howdy @swiftPunk, the data is coming from a json file so i cannot use Int

Comment: It is an example to help u to get the idea! Use my answers to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Using @workingdog 's comment i was able to fix it and posting the answer below in case it comes in handy.

```
struct Introductions: Codable, Identifiable {
   let id: String
   let topIntros: String?
   let image: String
   let date: String
}

ForEach(introductions) { introduction in
   NavigationLink(destination: IntroductionDetailView(introduction: introduction)) {
      IntroductionsView(introduction: introduction)
   }
}


struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack { 
if (introductions.count >= 5) {
    ForEach(introductions.prefix(upTo: 5), id:\.topIntros) { introduction in
       NavigationLink(destination: IntroductionDetailView(introduction: introduction)) {
          IntroductionsView(introduction: introduction)
       }
    }
} else {
ForEach(introductions) { introduction in
   NavigationLink(destination: IntroductionDetailView(introduction: introduction)) {
      IntroductionsView(introduction: introduction)
   }
}
}
}

    }
    
}
```

using .id broke the view hierarchy so i used the optional .topIntros and voila every turned out fine.